# Notification icon showing up in status bar but not in notification itself

Tags: android, android-notifications

[image]

[image]

---

As you can see, the mipmap icon is showing in the status bar but not in the notification itself. This is how I've set it:

```
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).
                setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher). // This is the small icon
                // more code
                build();
```

Current test device is using Android 7.1.1
Can anyone help or explain why this is happening, or give some advice on how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because Android requires a white icon in the notification bar. So change it to a white icon.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

What Android basically does, is painting your wall grey. Actually your wall is showing, but with a grey overlay.

According to your question below, you can load your drawable and paint it to white like this:

```
yourWallIcon.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE)
```

Note that `yourWallIcon` must be a drawable.

Comment: Why is it showing a colored wall in the status bar then? And other apps are showing colored icons in the notification itself

Comment: What API are you targeting?

Comment: API level 23, Android 6.0

Comment: API 26? That's the thing. Above API 19, notifications will be colored. You can't do anything, only targeting your app to API 19. But I will not recommend this. It violates the Material Design rules.

Comment: Do you perhaps know a way to color the mipmap icon to a white colored icon programmatically? If you do, would you mind editing your answer with that url.

Comment: You can use `Drawable.setColorFilter`